# Error con Text View

Tags: java, android, android-studio

mi `codigo` lanza un error cuando defino la id del `TextView`.

```
    package com.david.animefm2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.CollationElementIterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import static android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList radios;
    private RadioAdapter adapter;
    private ListView lvRadios;
    private String url ="";
    private String txt = "";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private AdView mAdView;

    TextView titulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etRadio);
    //TextView texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etRadio);

    //noti
    // Variables de la notificacion
    NotificationManager nm;
    Notification notif;
    static String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

    //Defino los iconos de la notificacion en la barra de notificacion
    int icono_v = R.drawable.animelayer;
    int icono_r = R.drawable.radioanime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //config
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9173335460606469/5989305154");
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdFailedToLoad");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                // covers the screen.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdOpened");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdLeftApplication");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
                // to the app after tapping on an ad.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
            }
        });

        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.start);
        //variables
        radios = new ArrayList<radio>();
        rellenarArrayList();
        adapter = new RadioAdapter(this, radios);
        lvRadios = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRadeo);
        lvRadios.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Lista
        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRadeo);
        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                SetUrl(i);
            }
        });

        // Inicio el servicio de notificaciones accediendo al servicio
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        // Realizo una notificacion por medio de un metodo hecho por mi
        notificacion(icono_r, "titulo contenido", "texto contenido", "texto extendido");

        //BOTON FLOTANTE

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    //metodo de pausa
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                } else {
                    BotonReproducir();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Nombre y icono
    private void rellenarArrayList() {
        radios.add(new radio("Radio Vocaloid", R.drawable.radiovocaloid));
        radios.add(new radio("Radio Anime", R.drawable.radioanime));
        radios.add(new radio("Anime Layer", R.drawable.animelayer));
        radios.add(new radio("Anime Radio SU", R.drawable.radioanimesu));
        radios.add(new radio("canario", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        radios.add(new radio("cerdo", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        radios.add(new radio("delfin", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        radios.add(new radio("gato", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        radios.add(new radio("iguana", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        radios.add(new radio("lince", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        radios.add(new radio("lobo", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        radios.add(new radio("morena", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        radios.add(new radio("orca", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        radios.add(new radio("perro", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        radios.add(new radio("vaca", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));

    };
    //Urls
    private void seturl(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                url= "http://curiosity.shoutca.st:8019/stream"; //Radio Vocaloid
                txt = "Radio Vocaloid";
                break;
            case 1:
                url="http://perseus.shoutca.st:9253/stream"; //Radio Anime
                txt = "Radio Anime";
                break;
            case 2:
                url="http://animelayer.ru:5190/play"; //Anime Layer
                txt = "Anime Layer";
                break;
            case 3:
                url="http://animeradio.su:8000"; //Radio Anime SU
                txt = "Radio Anime SU";
                break;
        };
        titulo.setText(txt);
        BotonReproducir();
    }

    private void SetUrl(int i){
        if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "posicion " + (i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        seturl(i);
    }

    private void BotonReproducir() {
        if (url != "") {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    //Inicia reproducción.
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bufering...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    // Lanzo la notificacion creada en el paso anterior
                    nm.notify(1, notif);
                    //fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Select a rario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    //notificacion

    public void notificacion(int icon, CharSequence textoEstado, CharSequence titulo, CharSequence texto) {
        // Capturo la hora del evento
        long hora = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Definimos la accion de la pulsacion sobre la notificacion (esto es opcional)
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        // Defino la notificacion, icono, texto y hora
        notif = new Notification(icon, "Holaaaaa", hora);
       // notif.(getApplicationContext(), "Old title", "Old notification content text", PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, new Intent(), 0));
        //Defino que la notificacion sea permamente
            //notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"7. onResume()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        nm.cancel(1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"7. onResume()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        nm.cancel(1);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"7. onResume()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        nm.notify(1, notif);
    }


}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-9173335460606469/5989305154"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNumCelda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="       BETA" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvRadeo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvNumCelda"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed"
        android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/star"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/radioanimesu" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Select a radio station"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="67dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

> 10-05 16:15:44.195 26479-26479/com.david.animefm2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: com.david.animefm2, PID: 26479
>                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.david.animefm2/com.david.animefm2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2849)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2457)
>                                                                           at com.david.animefm2.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:45)
>                                                                           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2839)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Comment: Publica el codigo del activity completo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia. Agrega el código de tu clase y de tu layout para saber porque se genera el error.

Comment: vale,es que es algo largo y un caos, he epezado hace muy poco a programar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a
>   null object reference at
>   android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2457) at
>   com.david.animefm2.MainActivity.

Necesitas un contexto para obtener la referencia de la vista, esta definición debes realizarla dentro del método `onCreate()`:

```
  TextView titulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etRadio);
```

Se realizaría de esta forma ya que la instancia del `TextView` además también la usas en otros métodos:

```
    //TextView titulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etRadio);
   private TextView titulo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    titulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etRadio);

   ...
   ...
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estas intentando instanciar la vista en la zona de variable, también las variables de notificación y los drawables, traslada ese código a la zona onCreate de tu clase:

```
 TextView titulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etRadio);

TextView titulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etRadio);
//TextView texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etRadio);

//noti
// Variables de la notificacion
NotificationManager nm;
Notification notif;
static String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

//Defino los iconos de la notificacion en la barra de notificacion
int icono_v = R.drawable.animelayer;
int icono_r = R.drawable.radioanime;
```

Quedaría asi:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView titulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etRadio);
    //noti
    // Variables de la notificacion
    NotificationManager nm;
    Notification notif;
    static String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

//Defino los iconos de la notificacion en la barra de notificacion
int icono_v = R.drawable.animelayer;
int icono_r = R.drawable.radioanime;

    //config
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9173335460606469/5989305154");
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdFailedToLoad");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
            // covers the screen.
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdOpened");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdLeftApplication");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
            // to the app after tapping on an ad.
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
        }
    });

    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.start);
    //variables
    radios = new ArrayList<radio>();
    rellenarArrayList();
    adapter = new RadioAdapter(this, radios);
    lvRadios = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRadeo);
    lvRadios.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Lista
    ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRadeo);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            SetUrl(i);
        }
    });

    // Inicio el servicio de notificaciones accediendo al servicio
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    // Realizo una notificacion por medio de un metodo hecho por mi
    notificacion(icono_r, "titulo contenido", "texto contenido", "texto extendido");

    //BOTON FLOTANTE

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                //metodo de pausa
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            } else {
                BotonReproducir();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

En las actividades las vistas se tienen que inicializar dentro del método `onCreate()`. Hay estas declarando e inicializando las vistas en la clase, por eso el error. Las variables las puedes declarar en la clase e inicializarlas en el metodo `OnCreate()`, tal como muestro a continuación.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ...

    // Declaras la variable
    TextView titulo;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Inicializas la variable
        titulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etRadio);

        ...

    }

    ...

}
```